# How do I use wildcards in an IN-clause

Tags: ms-access

Is it possible to use a wildcard like `#` to match items that start with a number in a IN-clause

The following works:
Criteria: `In ("2T","2TF","2TC","2TO","2TFC","2TOC","2C","2CO","2FC")`

However I'd like to catch also instances like "3TF" and "6TF"
But obviously the following does not work
Criteria: `In ("T","#TF","#TC","#TO","#TFC","#TOC","#C","#CO","#FC")`

Is there a way to handle this

UPDATE [attempt trying proposal of Erik A]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are trying to match any of those suffixes for a record with any single integer prefix, you could use a combination of `like` and `in` with the first character removed using `mid`, e.g.:

```
myfield like "#*" and
mid(myfield, 2) in ("T","TF","TC","TO","TFC","TOC","C","CO","FC")
```

Or alternatively, using only `like`:

```
myfield like #T or
myfield like #C or 
myfield like #T[FCO] or
myfield like #T[FO]C or
myfield like #CO or
myfield like #FC
```

Here, `T[FCO]` matches `TF`, `TC`, and `TO`; and similarly, `T[FO]C` matches `TFC` and `TOC`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Add *Like*:

```sql
Where 
    Field In ("2T","2TC","2TO","2TFC","2TOC","2C","2CO","2FC") Or
    Field Like "#TF"
```

Comment: @ErikA: You are right. I have corrected the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, without VBA, but with VBA it's quite easy:

Declare a function to do the matching:

```
Public Function InLike(DatabaseField As Variant, ParamArray LikeConditions() As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim v As Variant
    For Each v In LikeConditions
        If DatabaseField Like v Then
            InLike = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Then use it:

```
InLike (MyField, "T","#TF","#TC","#TO","#TFC","#TOC","#C","#CO","#FC")
```

Note that the first argument is the field, so it handles a little differently. Also, because it's VBA it carries a performance and compatibility impact.

Comment: I tried to get it working but it does not return any values. Most probably my mistake. I'm still new in Access and perhaps forgot something.

Comment: Can you share the full attempt? Likely, you made a simple error

Comment: I just added a small screen-shot. I did several attempts with different variables, but none returned a value.

Comment: Yeah, don't use design view... You should just do `InLike (MyField, "T","#TF","#TC","#TO","#TFC","#TOC","#C","#CO","#FC")`, not `InLike (MyField, "T","#TF","#TC","#TO","#TFC","#TOC","#C","#CO","#FC") = MyField` what is what you're doing now.